# Advice in making a color picker code for a certain function

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

I have a code for picking a few colors using `<button>` for html. Is there any way to turn this into color picker? I don't know how to get the value from the color picker to be used in a javascript function. Can anyone help me? Here are the codes that I have right now.

html

```
<span id="colors" > 

        <button  class="black" id="#000000"> </button>
        <button  class="white" id = '#FFFFFF'> </button>
        <button  class="blue" id = '#0000FF'> </button>
        <button  class="red" id = '#FF0000'> </button>
        <button  class="yellow" id = '#FFFF00'> </button>
        <button  class="green" id = '#008000'> </button>
        <button  class="purple" id = '#800080'> </button>

        <input type="hidden" id="color_value_form"> 

</span>
```

and here is the function in the javascript file.

```
$('#colors button').on('click', function(){
        tmp_ctx.strokeStyle = $(this).attr('id');
        tmp_ctx.fillStyle = tmp_ctx.strokeStyle;
        console.log(tmp_ctx.strokeStyle);

        drawBrush();
    })
```

Comment: Maybe of inspiration :) https://github.com/gibbok/react-color-picker-palette/blob/master/ColorPickerPalette.jsx

Comment: This is too broad I'm afriad. this kinda thing is currently quite complex. I'd have a google and try and pick an off the shelf package

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but here is something to start you off.

```js
$('#colors button').on('click', function(){
 document.body.style.background = $(this).data('color');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colors"> 
 <button class="black" data-color="#000000">black</button>
 <button class="white" data-color='#FFFFFF'>white </button>
 <button class="blue" data-color='#0000FF'>blue</button>
 <button class="red" data-color='#FF0000'>red</button>
 <button class="yellow" data-color='#FFFF00'>yellow </button>
 <button class="green" data-color='#008000'> green</button>
 <button class="purple" data-color='#800080'>purple </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html5 has colorpicker as well

```
 <input id="html5colorpicker" type="color">
```

in js:

```
$("#html5colorpicker").value //is a string like "#000000"
```

Comment: [This has very limited support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color), iOS safari and IE don't currently support this **at all**